# Mercurial : List/Copy files of whole changeset

Tags: mercurial

i looking to get the files which are tagged with a specific changeset.
I would like to copy it to another directory, how can i do it ?

Thankss

Comment: Tag refers to the whole changeset, not to particular files.

Comment: so if i was doing for changeset, how can i do it ?

Comment: how can you do *what*? All files belong to a particular commit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question isn't clear, but if you want a complete set of files from a specific tag just do:

```
hg archive -r <tag> <destinationdir>
```

See `hg help archive` for details.

Answer (score 0):

`hg st --change [rev]` will show a list of the files that changed in a given revision.  Since mercurial recognizes a tag name for a revision automatically (assuming it's unique to the revision hashes) this will work with a tag name as well.

If you want to copy these files in an automated fashion, you'll need a clean list; also, you probably just want the files that are there, not the ones removed/deleted.  For this you'd use

```
hg st -man --change [rev]
```

Using this list to copy these off somewhere else will be platform/shell dependent.  From Windows commandline, at the root of your repo, you could do something like

```
for /f %I in ('hg st -man --change [rev]') do copy ..\changes
```

, although that won't preserve subdirectory paths.  I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader :)

**UPDATE**

Sorry, I should also have noted that you'll need to update to the revision in question if you want to copy the files as they were at the time of said revision (I'm assuming here, but this seems like the natural reason to want to do this...).